# "Make easy" vs. "Make it easy"

Tags: zero-article, infinitive-vs-gerund, transitivity

I need to know which of these options is the correct one and why:

> - The Spanish cooking makes **it** easy to have a nice meal.
> - The Spanish cooking makes easy to have a nice meal.

I don't know if I need the pronoun "it" or not. By the way, is "a nice meal" correct, or should I use another adjective, such as "good"?

Answer (score 4):

Neither sentence is correct.

> Spanish cooking makes it easy to have a nice meal. [This is grammatical and natural]
>   Spanish cooking makes having a nice meal easy. [This is grammatical and natural]

You can use any adjective that suits your fancy instead of the [tepid](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tepid) *nice*.

Comment: Is it correct to say that the definite article is never used with gerunds?

Comment: @kiamlaluno I cannot think of a case when the definite article is used with a gerund, unlike in many (most?) other languages. I don't want to say that's a firm rule, though.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Actually, I take that back. You could say, "The solving of the puzzle was difficult."

Comment: @kiamlaluno The definite article may be used when a specific instance or type of *VERBing* is referred to: "The shooting of John Kennedy". When an article is employed, the direct object of *VERB* must be expressed as a phrase headed by *of*.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the OP's choices, the first one is correct. Why? Think of "makes it easy" as a phrasal verb — they just go together. The "it" here is *not* a pronoun. It's just part of the phrasal verb. Sometimes, however, we use "it" in other, weird ways. Read [this little article](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/minor/it.htm) I found for more information.