# "Be/Being on a diet is hard"

Tags: gerunds, infinitives

> ***Be on*** a diet is hard.
>   ***Being on*** a diet is hard.

I want to say that usually, for most people, doing a thing is very difficult. I want to say this is always true, a fact.

Which form do I have to use, *be* or *being*? And why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gerund is fine, but I cannot think of a case in which a 'bare infinitive' may be used as a nominal. As a rule you must use the 'marked infinitive': the infinitive preceded by *to*. So these are OK:

> **To be** on a diet is hard.
>    **Being** on a diet is hard. ... *and as Matt says, this is more common than the infinitive*

But this is not:

> <sup>✲</sup>**Be** on a diet is hard.

---

<sup>✲</sup> *marks an utterance as unacceptable*

Comment: +1, although I think you should also point out that "Being on a diet is hard" is much more idiomatic than the marked infinitive form. I would be surprised to hear "to be on a diet is hard" in ordinary non-academic conversation.

Comment: Stoney, can we say "*The* being on a diet is hard"? After all the gerund is a noun in English, so I'm actually wondering why we cannot place the determinative article before "being". Italian has both: "L'essere a dieta ..." and "Essere a dieta ...".

Comment: @Carlo_R. Under normal circumstances any determiner would be unidiomatic in that sentence. As I said earlier [today](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/6719/32), *the* is used with a gerund to indicate a particular instance of the action, not all instances, as here.  If you had been talking about many difficulties you *might* say "Of all these, it was the being on a diet which was hardest"; but even there the use of the article would 'mark' this instance of *being on a diet* as somehow different.

Comment: @Matt Quite right. I've incorporated that valuable observation.

Comment: Tank you! Let me check whether I have understood it properly or not: the sentence "Driving is dangerous" is ok, as well as "To drive is dangerous" (but it is more academic/formal). Instead "Drive is dangerous" is wrong. Am I right, @StoneyB?

Comment: @chiaraluna 98%. "To drive" is not more academic/formal, it's just uncommon at the head of a sentence as subject. I suspect this is because in this position it leads the hearer/reader to expect an infinitive of purpose: "To drive to Chicago you should take I-55."